# Get provisioning profiles through Xamarin Studio 6.3

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

since xamarin integrated the new function in xamarin studio, where we can add the apple developer account through fastlane, I have problems getting my prov profiles.

I installed fastlane, added my account but after hitting on refresh nothing happens.

[image]

Could please someone give a hand here?

Thanks

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I can see the profiles come down with 'fastlane sigh download_all' but they don't seem to be added into xamarin which stops device testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm running Xamarin Studio 6.3, on Sierra 10.12.4.

In my case, I was able to resolve it by clearing the directory ~/users/[your user]/library/mobiledevice/provisioningprofiles, then running "sigh download_all".

Comment: this is not working for me. How did you create the appId and the provisioning profile? Did you go through the iOS Developer website or just generated with the help of fastlane?

Comment: I created my certificates and profiles on the apple dev site.

I hope that helps; I'm still very new to fastlane, and I have yet to start enjoy working with it. I used to just download them through Xcode, and almost never had problems.

Comment: I forgot to mention, after I executed "sigh download_all", I restarted Xamarin Studio. I don't remember if I restarted my machine as well, but you might as well throw that in.

Comment: For me it didn't work. I restarted also the machine.

Comment: My context for this issue was I upgraded to XS 6.3, and shortly after, a client with their own certificate needed a hotfix.

I wound up downgrading to XS 6.2.1. Another team member is getting ramped up with fastlane, so hopefully I'll learn more about it in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Well everything now is clear. This is an official bug and will be fixed in the 15.3 Version (current 15.1)

Check [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55138) for more information.